# Node/Express: Notify User that they have been redirected due to unauthorized access

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Node newbie here

So I'm using Node(0.12.x) Express(4.x) & Passport(0.3.x) for authentication, and if the user accesses pages without the proper authentication a res.redirect('/login') will be preformed(by way of ensureLoggedIn('/login')). After a user is redirected to the login page I want to give the user some feedback to tell them they have been redirected ie. "You have been redirected due to unauthorized access, please login". How can I do this? My code below

```
app.get('/', require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn('/login'), function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(html_dir + 'form.html'), {
        user: req.user
    });
});
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(html_dir + 'login.html'));
});
app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send({
                success: false,
                message: err
            });
        }
        if (!user) {
            res.statusCode = 200;
            return res.status(200).send({
                success: false,
                message: "Incorrect username or password"
            });
        }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(500).send({
                    success: false,
                    message: err
                });
            }
            console.log("verified");
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader("Location", "/");
            return res.status(200).send({
                success: true
            });

        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```